# Cleaning up a useEffect warning with useReducer,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting these warnings:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
```

For some of my useEffects that pull data from an API with the help of my useReducer:

```
export default function  HomeBucketsExample(props) {
    const {mobileView} = props
    const [allDemoBuckets, dispatchAllBuckets] = useReducer(reducer, initialStateAllBuckets)
    const ListLoading = LoadingComponent(HomeBucketLists);
    
    useEffect(() =>
    {
        getAllDemoBuckets(dispatchAllBuckets);
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <ListLoading mobileView={ mobileView} isLoading={allDemoBuckets.loading} buckets={allDemoBuckets.data} />
    );
}
```

However, Im not sure how to clean up this effect above, I've tried mounting it using `True` and `False`, however the error still showed up. How can I fix my function above so the useEffect doesnt throw any warnings

EDIT:
code for my reduer:

```
export const getAllDemoBuckets = (dispatch) => axiosInstance
        .get('demo/all/')
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
            console.log('fired bucket-data')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR' })
        })


const initialStateAllBuckets = {
    loading: true,
    error: '',
    data: []
}

const reducer = (state, action) =>
{
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }
        case 'FETCH_ERROR':
            return {
                loading: false,
                data: {},
                error: "Something went wrong!"
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const [allDemoBuckets, dispatchAllBuckets] = useReducer(reducer, initialStateAllBuckets)
```

Comment: Add the reducer as well please. This error appears when you're dismounting the component before an answer from the API comes back and your component is trying to change state using that response.

Comment: Please see my new edit

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the warning is to tell you that *some action* is taking place after the component is unmounted and that the result of that work is going to be thrown away.

The solution isn't to try and work around it with a reducer; the solution is to cancel whatever is happening by returning a callback from useEffect. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ctrl = new AbortController();
  fetchExternalResource(ctrl.signal);
  return () => {
    ctrl.abort();
  }
}, []);
```

Using flags to determine if a component is mounted (ie using a reducer) to determine whether or not to update state is missing the point of the warning.

It's also okay to leave the warning up if this isn't actually an issue. It's just there to nit pick and tell you that, hey, you may want to clean this up. But it's not an error.

In your case, if you are using fetch, I would modify your code such that the function that dispatches actions can take an `AbortSignal` to cancel its operations. If you're not using fetch, there's not much you can do, and you should just ignore this warning. It's not a big deal.

It looks like you're using Axios for your requests. Axios supports a mechanism similar to abort signals - This should do the trick.

```
import { CancelToken } from 'axios';

const getAllDemoBuckets = async (dispatch, cancelToken) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('/demo/all', { cancelToken });
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
  } catch (err) {
    if ('isCancel' in err && err.isCancel()) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR' });
  }
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    getAllDemoBuckets(dispatch, source.token);
    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: How can I fix the useEffect warning I get when I use your code? Thank you very much.

Comment: My answer explains why the warning happens and how you avoid it - by cancelling the operation that causes the state update by returning a callback from useEffect.